# Изменение громкости mp3

Tags: java, gui, mp3

Создаю на Java программу-плеер. Мне необходимо помимо воспроизведения песни и добавления в плейлист реализовать изменение громкости песни и её позиции (с 00:04 на 01:24, например). Не подскажете, можно ли это реализовать с помощью AdvancedPlayer'а и каким образом это сделать? Если AdvPlayer не способен на такое, то подскажите, какая библиотека поможет реализовать мои планы?

[image: Это сам GUI программы]

Comment: А что за библиотека такая? Быстрое гугление ничего не дало.

Comment: AdvancedPlayer - библиотека JLayer. У меня JavaLayer версии 0.3

Comment: Тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648107/changing-volume-in-java-when-using-jlayer и тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134167/adjusting-volume-using-jlayer/17570819#17570819 рассказывается как менять громкость в этой либе. Думаю так же можно найти как меня позицию. Т.е. надо искать по всей библиотеке, а не по конкретному классу.

Comment: @Vartlok Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.